# Marking angles tkz-euclide part way round the curve

Tags: tkz-euclide

[image]I am trying to show the direction a the angle but cannot get the marking on the line partway round the curve. Here is my MWE,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
        \tkzDefPoint(-1,3){C}
        \tkzDefPoint(3,0){B}
        \tkzDrawSegments(A,B A,C)
        \tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
        \tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C)
        \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm, mark=at position 0.5 with arrows=<](C,A,B)
           \tkzMarkAngle[arc=l, size=1, mark=<-](C,A,B)
       \tkzMarkAngle[size=0.5cm, arrows=->](B,A,C) 
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{The angle}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

as you can see I have tried a few options but non of them work, any help?

Comment: I might see, if there was a screenshot ... ;-)

Comment: @MS-SPO but maybe a little smaller, not great with freehand.

Comment: change the order of `(C,A,B)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postaction and decorate seem to do the job.

```
\tkzMarkAngle[mark=None,size=0.5cm, postaction = {decorate, decoration={markings,mark = at position .5 with {\arrow{>}}}}](C,A,B)
```